# how can i open a file which is in a zip file

Tags: python, file, zip

I want to open a html file and that html file is in a zip file(both name is same) and i'm trying to open that html file.

```
old_file = input("DRAG:") #dir C:\Users\GG\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\f1dbef77-342b-4026-85d8-7f30fe691a63_f.zip        
file_parts = old_file.split(".") #[C:\Users\GG\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\f1dbef77-342b-4026-85d8-7f30fe691a63_f] [zip]        
first= file_parts[0]
direcs = first.split("\\")

file_itself = direcs[-1]  # the file name that i need to use
last = file_parts[1]


file = open(f'{first}.zip\\{file_itself}.html', encoding="UTF-8").read()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should first unzip the archive in a temporary folder, then you should open the file from there, and when everything is done, you may delete the folder in which you have extracted your data.

You may use python ZipFile as library and the `extract()` call to unzip your html.

See [ZipFile Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html)